# How should my PHP regular expression (regexp) look?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a long string containing some HTML and PHP text. In that string, I want to search for all occurrences of a couple of PHP function calls and get the parameters. Now I need help with the regular expression.

Functions to find: `link_to`, `link_to_function` and `mail_to`.

My uncompleted working copy:

```
$regexp = '...' // Help here please!

$str = "Bla bla bla <?php echo link_to('Lorem', 'Ipsum') ?> bla bla bla <?php echo link_to_function(\"Lorem2\", \"Ipsum2\") ?> bla bla bla...";

preg_match_all
(
  $regexp,
  $str,
  $matches
);
```

I want it to return something like this:

```
$matches = array
(
  [0] => array
  (
    [0] => "link_to('Lorem', 'Ipsum')"
    [1] => "link_to_function(\"Lorem2\", \"Ipsum2\")"
  )
  [1] => array
  (
    [0] => "Lorem"
    [1] => "Lorem2"
  )
  [2] => array
  (
    [0] => "Ipsum"
    [1] => "Ipsum2"
  )
);
```

As you can see the parameters can be surrounded by both single and double quotes. All type of characters should be possible in the parameters.

And one more thing: Every call can have one **or** two parameters.

Comment: In general, this is not possible.  A regex cannot be used to match arbitrary amounts of nested parentheses, which is a problem, because this is a valid function call: `link_to(((a) + 2*(b+c)) * (d - e))`.

Comment: ok, but in this case every parameter in the function calls is surrounded by ' or ". Maybe that change things?

Comment: Indeed; if that's always the case in your scenario, then it's likely to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to test separately for one or for two parameters. For two parameters you want something like this:

```
"link_to.*?\(\s*'(.*?)'\,\s*'(.*?)'\s*\)"
```

If you think you might need to catch double-quotes as well as single, change to:

```
"link_to.*?\(\s*['"](.*?)['"]\,\s*['"](.*?)['"]\s*\)"
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that. But it should find all three kinds of functions

Comment: I'm only seeing two examples. You might want to update your question to show all three kinds.

Comment: I wrote "Functions to find: link_to, link_to_function and mail_to". Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: your soloution doesn't work for the criterias i explained. With some adjustments it works for the basic case where both function calls has two parameters. But as I said it can be either one or two...

Doesn't work:

$regexp = "/link_to.*?\(\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]\,\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]\s*\)/"; // Help here please!

$str = "Bla bla bla <?php echo link_to('Lorem', 'Ipsum') ?> bla bla bla <?php echo link_to_function(\"Lorem2\") ?> bla bla bla...";

preg_match_all
(
  $regexp,
  $str,
  $matches
);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: I said right at the top that the example was for two parameters. I won't say it's impossible to check for varying numbers of parameters with a single pattern, but I dunno how to do it.

Comment: This seems to be working: "/(mail_to|link_to|link_to_function)\(\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"](\,\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]\s*)?\)/". It handles both one and two parameters, but I have another problem. If a function call looks like link_to('test ' . $test . ' test', 'test2') my regexp doesn't work because then the first parameter will be returned like "test " and not "test ' . $test . ' test" as I want... How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[a-z_]+\(\s*(?:['"](.*?)['"],?\s*)*\)
```

and refine if necessary, I have no php at hand...

Comment: This seems to be working: "/(mail_to|link_to|link_to_function)\(\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"](\,\s*[\'\"](.*?)[\'\"]\s*)?\)/". It handles both one and two parameters, but I have another problem. If a function call looks like link_to('test ' . $test . ' test', 'test2') my regexp doesn't work because then the first parameter will be returned like "test " and not "test ' . $test . ' test" as I want... How to fix?

Comment: @AndersKristiansson change the `['"]` two `('")` and match that with a back-reference `\n` at the end. So this would match the first parameter `('")(.*)\1`. The back-reference must be incremented in every sub-expression that should match another one: `('")(.*)\2` and so on.